# Listen for Visio MarkerEvent event in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, event-handling, visio

In MS Visio, I have a shape that represents area. I want my shape to update the area text every time it is changed. For this, I used QUEUEMARKER function in the shapesheet with a context string "Shape is changed" along with DEPENDSON. So, every time the shape is modified, it creates a MarkerEvent in the eventlist of Visio. 
I also have a COM Add-in in which I want to listen for this "Shape is changed" event so that once that event is triggered, I want to run one of the function that updates the area of the shape that is being modified.

I saw the example of MarkerEvent and Add Advise in Visio SDK and copied that, but I am not able to listen to the event. Can you please help me understand what am I doing wrong?

[image: MarkerEvent is triggered in Visio event monitor]

Here is the code that I adapted from Visio SDK:

```
    Private WithEvents visioApplication As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Application
Private beginQueuedEvent As Integer
Private endQueuedEvent As Integer
Private betweenMarker As Boolean

Public Sub UseMarker(ByVal markedPage As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Page)

    ' Get the Application object of the currently running Visio application.
    visioApplication = CType(markedPage.Application, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Application)

    Try

        betweenMarker = False

        beginQueuedEvent = visioApplication.QueueMarkerEvent("Shape is changed")


    Catch err As System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(err.Message)
    End Try

End Sub


Private Sub applicationMarkerEventHandler(ByVal theApplication As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Application, ByVal sequenceNumber As Integer, ByVal context As String) Handles visioApplication.MarkerEvent

    Try

        ' Ignore marker events with no context string
        If Not IsNothing(context) Then
            If context.Length() <> 0 Then

                ' If the value of sequenceNumber is either beginQueuedEvent or
                ' endQueuedEvent, the event results from the calls to the
                ' QueueMarkerEvent method.

                ' Note: betweenMarker is used in the 
                ' shapeAddedToPageEventHandler to process the ShapeAdded
                ' messages fired between the two QueueMarkerEvent calls. 

                If (sequenceNumber = beginQueuedEvent) Then

                    betweenMarker = True
                End If

            End If
        End If

    Catch err As System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(err.Message)
    End Try

End Sub


Private Sub shapeAddedToPageEventHandler(ByVal addedShape As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Shape) Handles visioApplication.CellChanged

    Dim dA As Double        'Area value
    Dim dP As Double        'Perimeter value
    Dim sName As String     'Shape name
    Dim xPS As Visio.Shape  'Visio Shape

    Try

        If (betweenMarker) Then

            xPS = Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.PrimaryItem

            If InStr(xPS.Name, ".") > 0 Then
                sName = Left(xPS.Name, InStr(xPS.Name, ".") - 1)
            Else
                sName = xPS.Name
            End If

            Select Case sName
                Case "My Area"
                    dA = xPS.AreaIU
                    dP = xPS.LengthIU

                    xPS.Cells("User.Area").FormulaForceU = dA
                    xPS.Cells("User.Perimeter").FormulaForceU = dP
            End Select

        End If

    Catch err As System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(err.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I was able to solve it on my own.

I was not raising the Application.MarkerEvent event correctly.

```
Private Sub applicationMarkerEventHandler(ByVal theApplication As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Application, ByVal sequenceNumber As Integer, ByVal context As String) Handles Application.MarkerEvent
```

It works now.